# unbound not starting after reboot

Tags: networking, server, 16.04, services, systemd

I just installed unbound on a fresh installed Ubuntu16.04 VPS. To be sure I issued an enable (which actually is done automatically during install)

```
sytemctl enable unbound
```

After restarting the server unbound failed to start and the syslog shows:

```
[...]
12:45:58 systemd[1]: Starting unbound.service...
12:45:58 unbound[1036]:  * Starting DNS server unbound
12:50:58 systemd[1]: unbound.service: Start operation timed out. Terminating.
12:50:58 systemd[1]: Failed to start unbound.service.
12:50:58 systemd[1]: unbound.service: Unit entered failed state.
12:50:58 systemd[1]: unbound.service: Failed with result 'timeout'.
12:55:01 unbound-anchor: /var/lib/unbound/root.key has content
12:55:01 unbound-anchor: success: the anchor is ok
[...]
```

Additionally, "journalctl" for the last boot shows more information:

```
[...]
12:50:58 systemd[1]: unbound.service: Start operation timed out. Terminating.
12:50:58 systemd[1]: Failed to start unbound.service.
12:50:58 systemd[1]: Dependency failed for Host and Network Name Lookups.
12:50:58 systemd[1]: nss-lookup.target: Job nss-lookup.target/start failed with result 'dependency'.
12:50:58 systemd[1]: unbound.service: Unit entered failed state.
12:50:58 systemd[1]: unbound.service: Failed with result 'timeout'.
12:50:58 systemd[1]: Reached target Multi-User System.
[...]
```

When I afterwards manually issue

```
systemctl start unbound
```

Then unbound starts as expected and the syslog shows:

```
12:58:32 systemd[1]: Starting unbound.service...
12:58:32 unbound[1268]:  * Starting DNS server unbound
12:58:34 unbound-anchor: /var/lib/unbound/root.key has content
12:58:34 unbound-anchor: success: the anchor is ok
12:58:34 unbound: [1284:0] notice: init module 0: validator
12:58:34 unbound: [1284:0] notice: init module 1: iterator
12:58:34 unbound: [1284:0] info: start of service (unbound 1.5.8).
12:58:34 unbound[1268]:    ...done.
12:58:34 systemd[1]: Started unbound.service.
```

The problem seems to relate to "nss-lookup", and I suspect that the network interface is not available fast enough, but for now I do not know how to solve that.